# Node.js SFTP error > Error: connect: An existing SFTP connection is already defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp

Within my node.js application I am using ssh2-sftp-client to upload an image every 5 seconds.

The upload is working, however when repeating the function, I get the error message

```
node .\upload.js
uploaded screenshot to server as test_screenshot_uploadI3Mjc.png (first run)
Error: connect: An existing SFTP connection is already defined (second run)
```

My code is:

```js
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();


function uploadScreenshot() {
    randomNumber = Buffer.from(Math.random().toString()).toString("base64").substring(10,15);
    filename = "test_screenshot_upload"+randomNumber+".png";
    sftp.connect({
      host: 'ssh.strato.de',
      port: '22',
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pass'
  }).then(() => {
    sftp.put('screenshot.png', '/path/folder/folder/'+filename);
  }).then(data => {
      console.log("uploaded screenshot to server as " + filename);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err, 'catch error');
  });  
}

function foo() {
    uploadScreenshot();
    setInterval(foo, 5000);
}

foo();
```

I tried to add `sftp.end();` after sftp.put, but this did not help. Could you give me a hint on what I have done incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

All I needed to do was move

```
let sftp = new Client();
```

into

```
function uploadScreenshot()
```

It's now working.

Comment: Thanks! That worked nicely. (If you like, you can accept your own answer)